# perl regex not matching string with newline character \n

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to use perl (v5.14.2) via a bash shell (GNU Bash-4.2) in Kubuntu (GNU/Linux) to search and replace a string that includes a newline character, but I'm not succeeding yet.

Here's the text file I'm searching:

```
<!-- filename: prac1.html -->

hello
kitty

blah blah blah
```

When I use a text editor's (Kate's) search-and-replace functionality or when I use a regex tester (http://regexpal.com/), I can easily get this regex to work:

```
hello\nkitty
```

But when using perl in the command line, none of the following commands have worked:

```
perl -p -i -e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.*kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]*kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
```

Actually, I got desperate and tried many other patterns, including all of these (different permutations in the "single-line" and "multi-line" modes):

```
perl -p -i -e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.kitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello.kitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html

perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]*kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]^kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]*^kitty,newtext,' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]*kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]^kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]*^kitty,newtext,s' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]kitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]*kitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]^kitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]*^kitty,newtext,m' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]kitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello[\S\s]*kitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]^kitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html
perl -p -i -e 's,hello$[\S\s]*^kitty,newtext,ms' prac1.html
```

(I also tried using \r \r\n \R \f \D etc., and global mode as well.)

Can anyone spot the issue or suggest a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try doing this, I make this possible by modifying the *input record separator* (a newline by default) :

```
perl -i -p00e 's,hello\nkitty,newtext,' prac1.html
```

from [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) :

> -0[octal/hexadecimal]
>
> specifies the input record separator ($/ ) as an octal or hexadecimal
>   number. If there are no digits, the null character is the separator.
>   Other switches may precede or follow the digits. For example, if you
>   have a version of find which can print filenames terminated by the
>   null character, you can say this:
>
> ```
> find . -name '*.orig' -print0 | perl -n0e unlink
> ```
>
> **The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode**.
>   Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by
>   convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.

Comment: I've been programming in perl for 20 years and I'd never heard of "paragraph mode" before.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @sputnick and @Bluby!  Here are a few websites that helped me make sense of the perl manual material: [Perl's Special Variables (input and output record separators, etc)](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/18/variables.html); [The ``diamond'' operator](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/perl/notes/node46.html); [The empty diamond operator (<>)](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~spector/extension/perl/notes/node47.html)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that "-p" has already implicitly wrapped this loop around your "-e", and the "<>" is splitting the input into lines, so your regexp never gets a chance to see more than one line.

```
 LINE:
       while (<>) {
           ...             # your program goes here
       } continue {
           print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
       }
```

See the perlrun manpage for more information.