# Regex doesn't match in Perl, does on Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regular expression that I am trying to match on strings containing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var debug = new Debugger();
</script>
```

I have determined it suffices to use the word "debug" to match on.

If I execute the command:

```
find . -name 'test.html' -exec perl -ne '/<script type="text\/javascript">[\S\s]*?(debug)[\S\s]*?<\/script>/ && print' '{}' \;
```

I would expect the regex to match, as the regex string

```
 <script type="text\/javascript">[\S\s]*?(debug)[\S\s]*?<\/script>
```

Matches on sublime text.

I have had trouble using [\S\s] with Perl.  Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Good luck with this kind of question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags is not so far

Comment: There may be differences in line break characters. Did you try adding \r and \R inside the brackets? It would look like: [\S\s\r\n]

Comment: It might help you see the cause of your issue if you replace your Perl command with something like this: `perl -nle 'print "^$_\$"'`. This will print a `^` at the beginning of each line and a `$` at the end of each line. For each line, think: "Is `<script` at the beginning *and* `</script>` at the end?"

Comment: Yes I have tried.  I believe \S\s is inclusive of \n and \r

Answer (score 0):

You want to use perl's paragraph mode (`-0`) when calling it. Using this, your regex will work:

```
find . -name 'test.html' -exec perl -n0e '/<script type="text\/javascript">[\S\s]*?(debug)[\S\s]*?<\/script>/ && print' '{}' \;
```

(Not?) surprisingly @sputnick gets the gold medal for this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905836/perl-regex-not-matching-string-with-newline-character-n) ;)

Answer (score 0):

**edit**  I failed to see there is a file slurp problem. But that just makes
two problems now.  Consider running a Perl script instead and modify the record
separator in a scope like `{ $/ = undef; $data = <$file>;  ... }` or similar.

---

You know the warning about using regex on html.

A point: `[\S\s]` is equivalent to `(?s:.)` using the inline modifier.
and won't be a problem in Perl.

The non-greedy won't help, it wants to find `debug` in a script tag, it will
take from the first tag and match all the other tags until it finds `debug` then
look for a close tag.

That's the only problem that could arise. To prevent that you have to check
the contents of the script a little better.

```
 #  /(?s)<script\s+type="text\/javascript">(?:(?!<\/?script).)*?(debug)(?:(?!<\/?script).)*?<\/script>/

 (?s)
 <script \s+ type="text/javascript">
 (?:
      (?! </?script )
      . 
 )*?
 ( debug )
 (?:
      (?! </?script )
      . 
 )*?
 </script>
```